# Handle multiple exceptions of same instance seperately

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception

If I have multiple method calls to another class that I cannot change and each could throw the same exception, how would I handle each Exception seperately without the rest of the function proceeding execution?

Example:

```
async mightThrowExceptions() {

    var call1 = await this.api.sampleMethod(); //Might throw exception of instance 'E'
    //Mustn't be called if call1 threw exception
    var call2 = await this.api.dependantFrom1(call1); //Might throw exception of instance 'E'
    //Mustn't be called if call2 threw exception
    var call3 = await this.api.dependantFrom2(call2); //Might throw exception of instance 'E'

    /*
    if call1 threw exception, do:
    console.log('call1 threw exception');

    if call1 threw exception, do:
    console.log('call2 threw exception');

    if call1 threw exception, do:
    console.log('call3 threw exception');
    */
}
```

Comment: Why do they all throw the same exception? That's the problem here.

Comment: Exactly. This is a class of someone else and I cannot influence or change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest try catchs:

```
 try {
   const a = await getA();
   try {
       const b = await getB(a);
       try {
        const c = await getC(b);
       } catch(e) {
         // handle c error, no control flow!
       }
    } catch(e) {
       // handle b error, no control flow!
    }
 } catch(e) {
    // handle c error, no control flow!
 }
```

However proper design would be if those functions throw different things, then one could do:

```
 try {
    await getC(await getB(await getA()));
 } catch(error) {
   if(error instanceof AError) {
      // ...
   } else if(error instanceof BError) {
       //...
    } else if(error instanceof CError) {
        //...
    } //?
 }
```